# canvas fillRect() not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new to canvas and java script and have no idea why it is not working. The 2 alerts are firing but color of the canvas is not changing every 1 sec as I intended it to do.

```
    var canvas = function(width, height, color){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    var instance = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(instance);
    instance.width = this.width;
    instance.height = this.height;
    var ctx = instance.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    this.changeBackground = function(color){
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }

    this.clear = function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }
    var flag = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(flag) {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            alert('blue');
        }
        else {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
            alert('green');
        }
        flag = !flag;
    },1000);
    }

    var gameCanvas = new canvas(800, 600, 'green');
```

Comment: giving a running example could help you see the problem and it will for sure help others to come faster with an answer. :) (you could use jsbin, plunker, jsfiddle etc)

Comment: You should also note that using the console is a huge part of debugging, and remember code must be unusable before it *is* usuable

Comment: Thanks for the info but console shows no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `this` inside of setInterval is the global `window` object, so `this.width` is `undefined`. The easiest way to fix this is to convert the function passed to `setInterval` into an arrow function. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38f2bj6c/)

```
setInterval(() => {
    ...
},1000);
```

Arrow functions inherit their context, so `this` is still your canvas object.

**Note:** arrow functions are not supported in IE v11 and below. [Here](https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions) is the list of supported browsers.

If you can't use arrow functions, you can get the size of the canvas from the `ctx` with `ctx.canvas.clientWidth` and `ctx.canvas.clientHeight` [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3bk3aoh/)

Comment: Using the arrow function fixed it. but any alternatives to this in case someone is using older browsers?

Comment: I added an example without arrow functions to my answer

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Writing `setInterval( () => {` instead of `setInterval(function(){` could solve this issue.

Fat-arrow function or lamda function or `() =>` will point `this` to your class-function instead of `window` variable.

Using `function()` inside a callback will always point `this` to the object that the implementation of used function came from.
In your case `setInterval` is a function of `window` global variable

Comment: yeah that did it. But I heard arrow functions are fairly new.. So any alternatives for older browsers?

Comment: you can try `.bind(this)` to explicitly say to the function which will be its `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(flag) {
 ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 alert('blue');
} 
else {
 ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 alert('green');
}
```

`this` inside setInterval contexts to `window`. Fixing this would fix your issue.